# I have assigned some text to lable, want to remove that \n from text and I need to dispaly text should be in multiple lines

Tags: xcode4.5

Now in my label text like:

a 28year old lady came to an obstetric clinic for  an consequevces\n

\n
what shoul the doctor do?\n

I want to dipaly text should be in lable like:

a 28year old lady came to an obstetric clinic for  an consequences

what shoul the doctor do?

Comment: You need to at least try something...

Answer (score 0):

You should do this...

```
NSString *tempString = @"a 28year old lady came to an obstetric clinic for an consequevces\n \n what shoul the doctor do?\n i want to dipaly text should be in lable like: a 28year old lady came to an obstetric clinic for an consequevces what shoul the doctor do?";
NSString *string = [tempString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];
```